# Select com condição de busca relacionada a data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu gostaria de saber se consigo criar condição no sql igual ao python por exemplo.
Contextualizando: eu tenho uma atualização diária automatizada que roda uma consulta todos os dias. Eu precisava que antes de rodar a rodar a consulta fosse identificado o dia, por exemplo, se hoje for dia 01 rodar tal consulta, se for qlq outro dia do mes rodar outra consulta.

eu tenho essa automação no zapier. Como funciona: todo dia ele envia por chat o resultado do dia anterior relacionado as metas diarias da empresa. O zapier vai la, roda a consulta no banco (Postgre ) e envia. porém eu preciso que exatamente no dia primeiro do mês ele me envie o compilado do mes anterior e nao só o resultado do dia anterior. Hoje, todo dia primeiro ele me envia de acordo com a consulta os resultados do dia 30 ou 31, mas eu preciso criar um condição na consulta que se for dia 01 ele roda uma consulta de compilado, se for qlq outro dia ele roda resultado do dia anterior,

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes , funções de Data dependem do SGBD em questão , informe o Banco, mas melhore a sua pergunta , eu por exemplo não entendi o problema totalmente.

Comment: sim é possível, para fazer algo automatizado normalmente se configura isso no banco de dados... qual o banco de dados que utiliza? edite e adicione essa informação na pergunta (nas tags tbm)

Comment: eu tenho essa automação no zapier. Como funciona: todo dia ele envia por chat o resultado do dia anterior relacionado as metas diarias da empresa. O zapier vai la, roda a consulta no banco (Postgre ) e envia. 

porém eu preciso que exatamente no dia primeiro do mês ele me envie o compilado do mes anterior e nao só o resultado do dia anterior. 
Hoje, todo dia primeiro ele me envia de acordo com a consulta os resultados do dia 30 ou 31, mas eu preciso criar um condição na consulta que se for dia 01 ele roda uma consulta de compilado, se for qlq outro dia ele roda resultado do dia anterior,

Answer (score -1):

Sim, é possível criar condições em consultas SQL, da mesma forma que é possível em outras linguagens de programação.

No caso específico que você descreveu, você pode utilizar a cláusula **CASE** para criar uma condição que verifique o dia atual e execute uma consulta diferente dependendo do resultado.

A sintaxe da cláusula **CASE** é a seguinte:

```
CASE
  WHEN condição THEN resultado
  [WHEN ... THEN ...]
  [ELSE resultado]
END
```

Por exemplo, a consulta abaixo verifica se o dia atual é igual a 1 e, se for, seleciona o total de vendas do mês anterior. Caso contrário, seleciona o total de vendas do dia anterior:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) = 1 THEN
      (SELECT SUM(preco_total) FROM vendas WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data_venda) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1)
    ELSE
      (SELECT SUM(preco_total) FROM vendas WHERE data_venda = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')
  END AS total_vendas
FROM dual;
```

Note que, nesse exemplo, estou utilizando a função **EXTRACT** para extrair o dia e o mês da data atual e comparando com a cláusula **WHEN** para verificar se o dia é igual a 1. Além disso, estou utilizando a função **SUM** para calcular o total de vendas e a cláusula **FROM** dual para selecionar um único valor.